# modify value in each row of a dataframe

Tags: r

I have an input called target and a dataframe:

```
target <- 3
d <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,3),y=c(4,5,6))

x y  
1 4   
2 5   
3 6
```

I want for each row:

if the value of column x < target then this value <- 0

if the value of column y > target then this value <- 9

the result:

```
x y   
0 9
0 9
3 9
```

how could I get this?

I tried to use the function `apply` but it didn't allow to modify the value in dataframe `d`.

Comment: I think you have a typo in the third row of your expected `x` output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With dplyr and case_when:

```
library(dplyr)
d <- d %<% 
mutate(target = 3,
       x = case_when(x < target ~ 0,
                     T ~ x),
       y = case_when(y > target ~ 9,
                     T ~ y))
```

With base r:

```
d$x[d$x < target,] <- 0
d$y[d$y > target,] <- 9
```

Comment: thank you for your response, i have a second question, if the target is a vector (same length as nrow(d) ). that means the target is different for each row. do the function mutate still work?

Comment: If you have a vector containing all of the targets e.g. `targets <- c(1, 2, 3)` then yes you can mutate this onto your data frame and then use case_when to compare with the targets column and change your x/y columns accordingly.

Comment: Essentially mutate will compare row by row but for this to work your target vector needs to be a column in your data frame. If you already have your target as a vector the dplyr example I posted should work except you would change the line `mutate(target = 3,` to be `mutate(target = target,` so that your target vector is now the "target" column of your data frame.

Comment: thanks a lot , i try with base r and that works! and if i want the target become the value that i want affect to (if the condition is true), i just run:  d$y[d$y > target,] <- target[d$y > target,]

Answer (score 1):

Multiple ways to do this. One way using double `replace`

```
replace(replace(d, d > target, 9), d < target, 0)

#  x y
#1 0 9
#2 0 9
#3 3 9
```

---

This logic can also be used in `dplyr` chain

```
library(dplyr)
d %>% mutate_all(funs(replace(replace(., . > target, 9), . < target, 0)))
```

Comment: thank you for your response, but if the target is also a vector  (same length as nrow(d). which means the target is different for each row. do the function mutate still work?

Comment: @DDchen nope, If you have `target` as vector I don't think `mutate` would work as it is as shown in the answer but `replace` would still work. Please check it on your real data.

Comment: @DDchen you are welcome. Just FYI, you can select only one answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

A straighforward way only using R base.

```
# Add object.
target <- 3

# Create dataframe.
df1 <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3),y=c(4, 5, 6))

# Copy dataframe [df1] to new dataframe [ðf2].
# Preserve old dataframe [df1] for comparison.
df2 <- df1

# Insert digits.
df2$x[df2$x < target] <- 0
df2$y[df2$y > target] <- 9
```